# parse xml with CDATA section using javascript - prevent execution of script

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xss

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<page>
<uri>http://www.somepage.com/page1.html</uri>
<content><![CDATA[<script>alert("Hello");</script>]]></content>
</page>
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Suppose i want to parse the xml using javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

txt=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("content")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.write(txt);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is an alert box with message as Hello. I do not want the script to execute.

Instead of xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("content")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
What can i do to get the output as :

```
<script>alert("Hello");</script>
```

Comment: `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("content")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` is perfect.  UPVOTED! :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't `document.write` it - that treats it as HTML, not text.

Use `createTextNode` and then `appendChild` the result somewhere in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have used this:

```js
    var config = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    config.async = false;
    config.loadXML(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var read = config.selectNodes("//bookstore/book/page/content")[0];
    alert(read);
```